# Better way to write jquery add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not an expert on JS and jQuery, but I would like to improve my knowledge.

I made this code that works for me, but I'm sure it can be done better. can you help me and explain how to synthesize it?
It's a piece of a slideshow when a URL is activated via a button, some images disappear and another appears.

```
<script>
  $(".green").click(function(e){
      window.location = "#img_green";
      $('#piz_green').css("display", "block");
      $('#piz_army').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_red').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_white').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_blue').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_black').css("display", "none");
  });
  $(".army").click(function(e){
      window.location = "#img_army";
      $('#piz_green').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_army').css("display", "block");
      $('#piz_red').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_white').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_blue').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_black').css("display", "none");
  });
  $(".red").click(function(e){
      window.location = "#img_red";
      $('#piz_green').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_army').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_red').css("display", "block");
      $('#piz_white').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_blue').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_black').css("display", "none");
  });
  $(".white").click(function(e){
      window.location = "#img_white";
      $('#piz_green').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_army').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_red').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_white').css("display", "block");
      $('#piz_blue').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_black').css("display", "none");
  });
  $(".blue").click(function(e){
      window.location = "#img_blue";
      $('#piz_green').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_army').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_red').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_white').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_blue').css("display", "block");
      $('#piz_black').css("display", "none");
  });
  $(".black").click(function(e){
      window.location = "#img_black";
      $('#piz_green').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_army').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_red').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_white').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_blue').css("display", "none");
      $('#piz_black').css("display", "block");
  });
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us also the minimal markup necessary for this script to work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, I don't have HTML ready because it's all in PHP and it's complex. But you can think just a few button that active the #url

Comment: Right click -> View Source -> copy -> paste in to question

Comment: pos off-topic here and better for code review SE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To improve this code we also can improve html a little. We can add some class to identify elements and controls and after that - we might need only 6 lines of js

Please try this

```js
$(".your-button-class").click(function(e) {
  const color = e.target.dataset.color;
  window.location = "#img_" + color;
  $('.your-div-class').css("display", "none");
  $('div[data-color=' + color + ']').css("display", "block");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="your-button-class" data-color="green">green</button>
  <button class="your-button-class" data-color="army">army</button>
  <button class="your-button-class" data-color="red">red</button>
  <button class="your-button-class" data-color="white">white</button>
  <button class="your-button-class" data-color="blue">blue</button>
  <button class="your-button-class" data-color="black">black</button>
</div>

<div class="your-div-class" data-color="green">green</div>
<div class="your-div-class" data-color="army">army</div>
<div class="your-div-class" data-color="red">red</div>
<div class="your-div-class" data-color="white">white</div>
<div class="your-div-class" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="your-div-class" data-color="black">black</div>
```

Comment: Yes this it's really better way. I use `data-hash` to give the # (I use a js library for the slideshow) I can also use the data-color? anyway I will test this one but sure it's a great solution.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for JavaScript here as you can do that with basic CSS as follows.

Use proper links with anchors:

```
<a href="#img_green">green</a>
<!-- repeat for other colors -->
<a href="#img_black">black</a>
```

Then use the [`:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) as follows:

```
#piz_green,
#piz_army,
#piz_red,
#piz_white,
#piz_blue,
#piz_black {
  display: none;
}
#piz_green:target,
#piz_army:target,
#piz_red:target,
#piz_white:target,
#piz_blue:target,
#piz_black:target {
  display: block;
}
```

And by adding a parent element, you can simplify it as follows:

```
#container > * {
  display: none;
}
#container > *:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I never think about this, it's very interesting. I will try also this solution. Thank you

Comment: Wow! I had no idea this pseudo-class existed and is even supported in IE 9. This is amazing and I will be using this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When I highly suggest the use of common classes in this case, you could always use comma `,` separator in you selectors with `show()/hide()` to simplify your code (a little) like :

```js
$(".green").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_green";
  $('#piz_green').show();
  $('#piz_army,#piz_red,#piz_white,#piz_blue,#piz_black').hide();
});

$(".army").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_army";
  $('#piz_army').show();
  $('#piz_green,#piz_red,#piz_white,#piz_blue,#piz_black').hide();
});

$(".red").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_red";
  $('#piz_red').show();
  $('#piz_green,#piz_army,#piz_white,#piz_blue,#piz_black').hide();
});

$(".white").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_white";
  $('#piz_white').show();
  $('#piz_green,#piz_army,#piz_red,#piz_blue,#piz_black').hide();
});

$(".blue").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_blue";
  $('#piz_blue').show();
  $('#piz_green,#piz_army,#piz_red,#piz_white,#piz_black').hide();
});

$(".black").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_black";
  $('#piz_black').show();
  $('#piz_green,#piz_army,#piz_red,#piz_white,#piz_blue').hide();
});
```

**Another suggestion with no need to change your HTML structure:**

```js
$(".green, .army, .red, .white, .blue, .black").click(function(e) {
  var color = $(this).prop('class');

  window.location = "#img_" + color;
  $('[id^=piz_]').hide();
  $('#piz_' + color).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't think that was possible uns comma.

Comment: Sort of an improvement, but still has tons of repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

Data attributes on the elements and a common class would make your life easier

```js
var slides = $(".slide");  // reference all the slides
$("[data-action").on("click", function(e){ // bind the click
  var btn = $(this);  // button that was clicked
  var color = btn.data("action");  // get the color
  slides.attr("hidden", true); // hide all the slides
  $("#piz_" + color).removeAttr("hidden");  // show the clicked color
  window.location.hash = "img_" + color;  // update the hash
});
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-action="green">Green</button>
<button data-action="red">Red</button>
<button data-action="blue">Blue</button>

<div class="slide_wrapper">
  <div class="slide" id="piz_green">green</div>
  <div class="slide" id="piz_red">red</div>
  <div class="slide" id="piz_blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The class slide is not necessary. You can just use: $('.slide_wrapper').children().attr("hidden", true); in your case.

Comment: Thank you guys! I see there are a lot of things that is possible do!

Answer (score 1):

```
function slideshow(image_id, block_id){
      window.location = image_id;
      $("[id^=piz_]").css("display", "none");
      $(block_id).css("display", "block");
  }

  $(".green").click(function(e){
      slideshow("#img_green", "#piz_green");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I would go with. First I would add an arbitrary data attribute, in this case, colour. Then I would add all my buttons with a corresponding data attribute. Then attach to the click event of those buttons and call the following code.

```js
$('[data-action=toggle]').click(function(e){
  $('div[data-color]:not([data-color='  + e.target.dataset.color + '])').hide();
  $('div[data-color=' + e.target.dataset.color + ']').show();
})
```

```css
a{
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-color="green">green</div>
<div data-color="red">red</div>
<div data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div data-color="pink">pink</div>
<div data-color="yellow">yellow</div>

<a href="#" id="green" data-action="toggle" data-color="green">Green</a>
<a href="#" id="green" data-action="toggle" data-color="red">Red</a>
<a href="#" id="green" data-action="toggle" data-color="blue">Blue</a>
<a href="#" id="green" data-action="toggle" data-color="pink">Pink</a>
<a href="#" id="green" data-action="toggle" data-color="yellow">Yellow</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider attribute selector to hide all the element at once. Make sure to call `hide()` before `show()`

```js
$(".green").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_green";
   $('[id^=piz]').hide();
   $('#piz_green').show();

});

$(".army").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_army";
  $('[id^=piz]').hide();
  $('#piz_army').show();
});

$(".red").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_red";
  $('[id^=piz]').hide();
  $('#piz_red').show();
});

$(".white").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_white";
  $('[id^=piz]').hide();
  $('#piz_white').show();
});

$(".blue").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_blue";
  $('[id^=piz]').hide();
  $('#piz_blue').show();
});

$(".black").click(function(e) {
  window.location = "#img_black";
  $('[id^=piz]').hide();
  $('#piz_black').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store id of the image you want to show as custom data attribute with each button and then hide all images (by giving them a common class) with one line and show only the image you need by it's id from custom data attribute.

Example of button element:

```
<button data-slideshow-button="green">Green</button>
```

Example of slideshow element:

```
<div id="piz_green" class="slideshow-image"></div>
```

And then just run code like this as click handler:

```
$('[data-slideshow-button]').click(function(e){
  var showId = $(e.currentTarget).data('slideshowButton');
  window.location = '#img_' + showId;
  $('.slideshow-image').hide();
  $('#piz_' + showId).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did use `piz_` for all classes in your HTML, you can easily use them in your JavaScript. For example, if you want to hide them all you can just type:
`$('[class^=piz_]').hide();`. This will hide all elements where the class starts with `piz_`.

Now I made a quick example with this in action. Please know I made just tile and a retry button to give you an example.

```js
$("[class^=piz_]").click(function(){ // Make all div's with the class piz_* clickable
   $('[class^=piz_]').hide(); // Hide all elements
   var classAttr = '.'+$(this).attr("class");  // Get the class from the tile you clicked on
   $(classAttr).show(); // Show all tiles with the same class
});

// This is just to get all tiles back and try it again.
$('.retry').click(function() {
 $('[class^=piz_]').show(); 
});
```

```css
.piz_green { background:green; } 
.piz_blue { background:blue; } 
.piz_red { background:red; } 
.piz_orange { background:orange; } 

div, button { width:100px; height:100px; }
.retry { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="piz_green"></div>
<div class="piz_blue"></div>
<div class="piz_red"></div>
<div class="piz_orange"></div>
<div class="piz_green"></div>

<button class="retry">
Retry!
</button>
```